# Open Linking.openURL(url) in a WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a login function in React Native:

```
  startLoginProcess(conf) {
    this.setConf(conf);
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
      const { url, state } = this.getLoginURL();
      this.state = {
        ...this.state,
        resolve,
        reject,
        state,
      };
      Linking.openURL(url);
    }));
  }
```

Recently, my app was rejected by Apple due to opening up a separate window for login.

Is there a way to force Linking.openURL to use the webview? I've looked through the documentation on both and I am not seeing a method.

Comment: Could you not just change the source of the webview?

Comment: @DerekLawrence I am not currently using a webview for the login process. Apple has rejected the app and is essentially demanding I do so. So I am trying to figure out how here